# passing multiple parameters into route helpers link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, nested, resources, link-to

I am new to Rails. I am trying to build a website. Below is my data models:

```
- user: 
has_many :created_events, foreign_key: "creator_id", class_name: "Event"
has_many :guest_events, foreign_key: "attendee_id"
has_many :attended_events, through: :guest_events

- event: 
belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
has_many :event_guests, foreign_key: "attended_event_id"
has_many :attendee, through: :event_guests

- event_guest: 
belongs_to :attendee, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :attended_event, class_name: "Event
```

I want my user to be able to attend an event so I created a `link_to` in the `user/show.html.erb`. If they already sign in and attend that event, they can choose to not attend that event anymore by click another `link_to` helper in the view.

My problem is when user click "**Not attend**" link, I've got an error saying:

```
No route matches [GET] "/events/7/event_guests.4"
```

- `config/routes.rb` file:

  ```
   resources :events do 
     resources :event_guests, only: [:create, :destroy]
   end
   resource :user do 
     resources :events 
   end
  ```
- Event_guests routes:

  ```
    Prefix Verb                URI Pattern                         Controller#Action
    event_event_guests POST   /events/:event_id/event_guests(.:format)     event_guests#create
    event_event_guest DELETE /events/:event_id/event_guests/:id(.:format) event_guests#destroy
  ```
- `EventsController`:

  ```
   def show 
     @event = Event.find(params[:id])
     @event_guest = EventGuest.where("attended_event_id = ? AND attendee_id = ?", @event.id, current_user.id)
     if @event_guest.exists? 
       @event_guest = @event_guest.take 
     else 
       @event_guest = nil 
     end
   end
  ```
- `EventGuestsController`:

  ```
   def destroy 
     if EventGuest.exist?(params[:id])
       @event_guest = EventGuest.find(params[:id])
       @event_guest.destroy 
     end
     redirect_to root, status: :see_other
   end
  ```
- `link_to` helpers in `user/show.html.erb`:

  ```
   <%= link_to "Attend", event_event_guests_path(@event), data: { turbo_method: "post" } %>
   <% if user_signed_in? &&  !@event_guest.nil? %>
     <%= link_to "Not attend", event_event_guests_path(@event, @event_guest), data: {turbo_method: "delete" } %>
   <% end %>
  ```

In the `link_to "Not attend"` helper, I tried:

- `event_event_guests_path(@event.id, @event_guest.id)`
- `event_event_guests_path(@event, :id => @event_guest.id)`
- `event_event_guests_path(:event_id => @event.id, :id => @event_guest.id)`

But none of them worked. I used `devise` to authenticate user.
Please help me! Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to use `event_event_guest_path` instead of `event_event_guests_path`, for example `event_event_guest_path(@event.id, @event_guest)`

Comment: @AbM oh my God, thank you, can't believe i made such a stupid typo mistake